# Calling a wsdl in php over https using Zend Soap Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, https, wsdl

When I'm trying to connect to a webservice I always get the next fault

SoapFault exception: [s:Sender] An error occurred when verifying security for the message

I also have to use a security header, full soap request is send:

```
<env:Envelope>
<env:Header>
<ns2:Action env:mustUnderstand="1">
http://ws.agiv.be/crabtools/ICRABTools/GetAddressLocation
</ns2:Action>
<ns2:MessageID>urn:uuid:10000001blsd-ghfs</ns2:MessageID>
<ns2:ReplyTo>
<ns2:Address>
http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous                      
</ns2:Address>
</ns2:ReplyTo>
<ns2:To>https://grab.beta.agiv.be/Tools/CRABTools.svc</ns2:To>
<o:Security env:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsu:Timestamp env:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsu:Created>2010-06-09T13:44:19Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2010-06-09T13:49:19Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
<o:UsernameToken>
<o:Username>myUsername</o:Username>
<o:Password>myPassword</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
</o:Security>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
<ns1:GetAddressLocation>
<ns1:houseNumberId>2306852</ns1:houseNumberId>
</ns1:GetAddressLocation>
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

My username and password are correct, I have allready tried to change the expiration date later but that doesn't solve it.

**What else could be the reason for this fault?**

Maybe I have to configure more things in my php-code.

I created a class that overrides Zend_Soap_Client

```
public function __soapCall($function_name, $arguments, $options=null, $input_headers=null, $output_headers=null) {
        $inputheaders = array($this->wsactionheader(),$this->unencryptedSecurityHeader());
        $result = parent::__soapCall($this->functionname, $arguments, $options, $inputheaders);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: I override Zend__Soap_client, updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help if you tell us what kind of server you are trying to connect to.
Also please provide the request headers in here. Use code like this

```
echo "REQUEST HEADERS:\n" . $client->getLastRequestHeaders() . "\n";
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

What you can do is:

1) Make sure you have specified the wsdl in your soap client.

2) It may be the "namespacing" problem. Make sure that your SOAP requests are using the same "envelope" format as your server (specified in WSDL), i.e. check namespace attributes like

```
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
```

If the namespace is different from the one in your wsdl try to avoid explicitly specifying 'soap_version' in built-in PHP SoapClient which is wrapped in Zend_Soap_Client. The former  always does specify the 'soap_version', this results in `xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"`

3) Ask for working request XML examples and/or full HTTP trace and compare (diff) them with yours.